# SSRS report empty text box with no dataset default to Times New Roman font when exported to word

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

The issue is,

1.Create an empty text box with no dataset tied .

2.Set the font to any font like arial 10 apart from Times new roman on the textbox font properties.

3.Export the report as .doc or .docx and try editing the content of text box in word.You will see Times new roman font.

There's a thread [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42434be3-5189-4169-a7b1-4d2236bcd83b/ssrs-text-box-after-word-export-changes-font-to-times-new-roman-even-though-we-had-applied-arial-10?forum=sqlreportingservices&prof=required) on 2016 discussed about this, and decided this issue was kinda bug. So I'm wondering after two years if this have been resolved or any workaround to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this with SSRS 2012 and got the same result. The workaround that helped me was to put a space in the text box. Doing so retained the the font set in SSRS.